# how to pass reference by reference in java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have BST that implements by linked list and I want to find an object by id of my nodes by start searching from the root and put it in key. so I have to pass the reference by reference , not by value; how can I do that?(key is a variable that declare out of function) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udLuz.jpg)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass by reference in Java.

You can emulate pass-by-reference by holding the "variable" as an element in an array or field in an object, and pass the reference to that array or object, and that will allow changes to the "variable" to be shared between scopes.